# Currying in C++

Tags: c++, currying, c++-concepts

Suppose you wanted to add some spice to your usual C++:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

#define fwd(o) forward<decltype(o)>(o)
  
template <class Functor, class ArgTuple>
concept Callable = requires(Functor f, ArgTuple args) {
  { apply(f, args) };
};

template <class Functor, class... Args>
class Curried {
  Functor fun_;
  tuple<Args...> collected_args_;
  
public:
  constexpr Curried(Functor f, tuple<Args...> args) : fun_(f), collected_args_(args) {}
  
  template <class... NewArgs>
  constexpr auto operator()(NewArgs&&... new_args) {
    auto args = tuple_cat(collected_args_, make_tuple(fwd(new_args)...));
    if constexpr (Callable<Functor, decltype(args)>) {
      return apply(fun_, args);
    } else {
      return Curried<Functor, Args..., NewArgs...>(fun_, args);
    }
  }
};

template <class Functor>
auto curry(Functor&& f) {
  return Curried<Functor>(fwd(f), {});
}

int main() {
  auto f = [](int a, int b, int c) { return a + b * c; };
  auto g = curry(f)(2, 3);
  static_assert(g(5) == 17);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, it would be fine if this compiled, but I am obviously misunderstanding the semantics of `requires`, since Clang says

```
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1416:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    _VSTD::__invoke_constexpr(
    ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:782:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE
              ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1413:26: note: in instantiation of exception specification for '__apply_tuple_impl<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &, std::__1::tuple<int, int> &, 0, 1>' requested here
constexpr decltype(auto) __apply_tuple_impl(_Fn && __f, _Tuple && __t,
                         ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1425:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__apply_tuple_impl<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &, std::__1::tuple<int, int> &, 0, 1>' requested here
    _VSTD::__apply_tuple_impl(
           ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:1423:26: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'apply<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &, std::__1::tuple<int, int> &>' requested here
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(_Fn && __f, _Tuple && __t)
                         ^
./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:11:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::apply<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &, std::__1::tuple<int, int> &>' requested here
  { apply(f, args) };
    ^
./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:11:5: note: in instantiation of requirement here
  { apply(f, args) };
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:10:20: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
concept Callable = requires(Functor f, ArgTuple args) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:25:19: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'Callable<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &, std::__1::tuple<int, int> >' requested here
    if constexpr (Callable<Functor, decltype(args)>) {
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:40:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Curried<(lambda at ./src/csc_cpp/currying.cpp:39:12) &>::operator()<int, int>' requested here
  auto g = curry(f)(2, 3);
                   ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:1660:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    ~__nat() = delete;
    ^
```

So the line inside of `requires` does not compile: perfect, why does not the compiler call it a day and simply say the constraint is unsatisfied? How should this be expressed properly?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with C++20 concepts to chime in, but I note you're still using llvm-10. llvm-10 was released in early 2020 (with the last release of it in mid-2020); the C++20 standard wasn't finalized until late 2020. They probably supported most of C++20 based on the draft standards, but it seems like you'd want to use a post-standardization release to make sure any last changes were incorporated.

Comment: I'd start with replacing `{}` by an explicit `std::tuple{}`. You may have stumbled into a non-deduced context.

Comment: Also... I don't believe `std::apply` must be sfinae friendly. Checking that the call expression is valid won't tell you if the arguments are valid.

Comment: there is `std::is_invocable_v` ? And second return in `Curried::operator() ` doesn't result in invoke, it returns an instance of another `Curried<>`. Oh, and there is  `std::forward_as_tuple`. In general it doesn't look like it can work that way, you'd end in infinite sequence, because there is no no-parameter operator()

Comment: It looks to me that you want to apply when you have enough arguments to call the function. But there is no protection against applying too many arguments. I think you should collect arguments one by one testing if the function is callable after each. Otherwise you can overshoot and never get a compiler error. Note: what about arguments with default? You will call such function too early.

Comment: It seems to me that this question could be improved by having more text describing the situation and less reliance on the code to explain things.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `is_invocable` is a workaround, thanks!